# Displaying a large table "the angular way"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to display a large dataset in a table.

First, I simply used nested ng-repeats:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <td>{{row.meta}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row.cells">{{cell.data}}</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

(That code is an example of what I mean, it doesn't actually correspond to my dataset. The code below does.)

This code is very clean, but it easily takes a few seconds to render. The dataset is quite large (thousands of cells fit on the screen).

I rewrote it to this monstrosity:

```
angular.module('systeem3').directive('dayStatusTable', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            housestatus: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            // Doing this manually since the Angular way is slooow....
            scope.$watch('housestatus', function(newValue) {
                if (newValue && Array.isArray(newValue)) {
                    var stringparts = ['<table>'];
                    for (houseline of newValue) {
                        stringparts.push('<tr><td>'+houseline.houseName+'</td>');
                        for (day of houseline.daystatus) {
                            var date = day.date.split('-')[2];
                            var weekday = day.date.split('-')[3];
                            var weekendOrWeekday = (weekday == 0 || weekday == 6) ? 'weekend' : 'weekday';
                            stringparts.push('<td class="',
                                             day.status, ' ',weekendOrWeekday,
                                             '">',
                                             date,
                                             '</td>');
                        }
                        stringparts.push('</tr>');
                    }
                    stringparts.push('</table>');

                    elem.html(stringparts.join(''));
                }
            });
        },
    }
});
```

The result was astonishing: it went from taking several seconds to render to less than 50ms, most of it taken up by the `elem.html()` call.

However, the code looks horrible, and very un-angular. How can I improve that?

Comment: IMO, this should be posted at `codereview.stackexchange.com`

Comment: Perhaps. I was hesitant to put it there or here. It would fit there since I'm asking about imporving my code, but it would fit here since I'm also asking about how to render a large table in angular in general.

Comment: The two solutions you posted are very different. Using `ng-repeat`, Angular is creating a scope object for each row and cell, as well as setting up watchers to give you data binding. Your custom directive is just generating static HTML. But your directive isn't "Un-angular" - you are still working within the framework by using a custom directive.

Comment: Ah, so this is the way I'm "supposed" to do it? (If there is such a thing, and setting aside things like decomposition unrelated to Angular.)

Comment: Yes, although as enkryptor's answer alluded to, virtualization can be even better. Having a large number of (even static) nodes in the DOM will degrade overall performance.

Answer (score 1):

For a really large table check [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/). It supports virtualization (it doesn't add to DOM rows if they aren't visible right now) and can work with 10,000+ rows quite smoothly.

Comment: Perhaps It's a bit heavy for what I'm looking for, it seems to be rather oriented towards spreadsheet-like data. The tables in the examples shown are also not nearly as compact as mine, the example I gave easily has 2000+ cells on the screen at the same time.